# Is there a way to convert IAsyncEnumerable to Stream?

Tags: c#, .net-core, stream, grpc

I'd like to send out a PUT request that has a `Stream InputStream` property, however, I only have an `IAsyncStreamReader` from a gRPC service which I can convert at most to an `IAsyncEnumerable` if I call `ReadAllAsync()` on it.

The only thing I can think of is:

```
await foreach (var item in requestStream.ReadAllAsync())
{
    await request.InputStream.WriteAsync(item.Data.ToByteArray());
}
// Send PUT request
```

In this case, however, I can only send the PUT request after the entire enumerable has been read which cannot be done for large amounts of data.

Comment: What library are you using for your PUT requests?

Comment: I'm using the standard .NET AWS SDK. I actually had some progress and made it work by creating a custom derived class from `Stream` where I override ReadAsync and thus avoid pulling the entire file in memory by reading chunks from `IAsyncStreamReader` and awaiting `MoveNext()`. 

Unfortunately, I could not manage to modify the buffer size that AWS specifies for reading from the stream even after explicitly setting it - it was always the default 81920 bytes. Though I've moved that problem to a separate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917654/aws-s3-buffer-size-not-increasing.