# AWS S3 buffer size not increasing

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

I am creating an S3 client with a modified buffer size, however, it does not seem to make a difference as always the same amount of bytes is read from the stream. Example code:

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(access, secret, token, new AmazonS3Config
{
     RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
     BufferSize = 1000000, // 1 MB (completely arbitrary)
});

await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest 
{
     Key = fileName,
     Bucket = bucketName,
     InputStream = new MyCustomStream(...)
});
```

When I debug this example, however, instead of reading a megabyte at a time from `MyCustomStream`, the buffer size is 81920 bytes which is the default for `Stream`. This leads me to think that the AWS implementation has not overridden the size.

From the documentation I assume that this is the correct property - `int BufferSize : The BufferSize controls the buffer used to read in from input streams and write out to the request.` I am indeed reading from an input stream so I would expect that this would get overridden.